# Reversing a vector in Coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to reverse a vector in Coq. My implementation is as follows:

```
Fixpoint vappend {T : Type} {n m} (v1 : vect T n) (v2 : vect T m)
  : vect T (plus n m) :=
  match v1 in vect _ n return vect T (plus n m) with
  | vnil => v2
  | x ::: v1' => x ::: (vappend v1' v2)
  end.

Theorem plus_n_S : forall n m, plus n (S m) = S (plus n m).
Proof.
  intros. induction n; auto.
  - simpl. rewrite <- IHn. auto.
Qed.

Theorem plus_n_O : forall n, plus n O = n.
Proof.
  induction n.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl. rewrite IHn. reflexivity.
Qed.

Definition vreverse {T : Type} {n} (v : vect T n) : vect T n.
  induction v.
  - apply [[]].
  - rewrite <- plus_n_O. simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_S.
    apply (vappend IHv (t ::: [[]])).
  Show Proof.
Defined.
```

The problem is, when I try to compute the function, it produces something like:

```
match plus_n_O (S (S O)) in (_ = y) return (vect nat y) with
...
```

and couldn't get further. What's the problem here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Which expression are you trying to compute, exactly?

Comment: Actually any expression that isn't empty, e.g. O ::: O ::: [[]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your functions use opaque proofs, `plus_n_S` and `plus_n_O`. To compute `vreverse`, you need to compute these proofs, and if they are opaque, the computation will be blocked.

You can fix this issue by defining the functions transparently. Personally, I prefer not to use proof mode when doing this, since it is easier to see what is going on. (I have used the standard library definition of vectors here.)

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Import VectorNotations.

Fixpoint vappend {T : Type} {n m} (v1 : t T n) (v2 : t T m)
  : t T (plus n m) :=
  match v1 in t _ n return t T (plus n m) with
  | [] => v2
  | x :: v1' => x :: vappend v1' v2
  end.

Fixpoint plus_n_S n m : n + S m = S (n + m) :=
  match n with
  | 0 => eq_refl
  | S n => f_equal S (plus_n_S n m)
  end.

Fixpoint plus_n_O n : n + 0 = n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => eq_refl
  | S n => f_equal S (plus_n_O n)
  end.

Fixpoint vreverse {T : Type} {n} (v : t T n) : t T n :=
  match v in t _ n return t T n with
  | [] => []
  | x :: v =>
    eq_rect _ (t T)
      (eq_rect _ (t T) (vappend (vreverse v) [x]) _ (plus_n_S _ 0))
              _ (f_equal S ( plus_n_O _))
  end.

Compute vreverse (1 :: 2 :: 3 :: []).
```